# How to overload << operator for cv::Filestorage?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to write my MarkerDistance struct to a file, using cv::FileStorage class.

I tried to overload the << operator in various ways but it doesn't compile.
And I am not sure what exactly is wrong. Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
struct MarkerDistance
{
    std::string linkName;
    double distance;

    MarkerDistance(std::string a, double b)
    {
        linkName = a;
        distance = b;
    }
    //Version 1
    cv::FileStorage & MarkerDistance::operator<< (cv::FileStorage &  fs)
    {
        std::string link = "linkName : " + linkName + "\n";
        std::string dist = "distance : " + std::to_string(distance) + "\n";
        std::string erg = link + dist;
        fs << erg;
    }

    //Version 2
    std::ostream& MarkerDistance::operator << (std::ostream& os)
    {
       // write obj to stream
       std::string link = "linkName : " + linkName + "\n";
       std::string dist = "distance : " + std::to_string(distance) + "\n";
       std::string erg = link + dist;
       return os << erg;
    }
};
```

Errormessage:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator<<` should have the following signature:

```
std::ostream& MarkerDistance::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MarkerDistance& obj);
```

or

```
cv::FileStorage& MarkerDistance::operator<<(cv::FileStorage& os, const MarkerDistance& obj);
```

Comment: Thank you but in that way I get a "to many arguments" error message.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709048/c-overloading-operator-for-struct-error-too-many-parameters

Comment: ok, I just deleted the MarkerDistance:: part and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @R_Valdez, Nice to know )